# Tree traversing or what?

Tags: python, tree, nlp

In Python, I'm writing a Natural Language Processing module and can't work out how to code a function to do the following.
Input: a list of parts of speech (POS) derived from an inputted sentence as short strings. Some items in the list are themselves lists because that part of the program doesn't know which part of speech to choose out of two or more possibles.
e.g. a particular six word sentence results in `["DET", "NOUN", ["VERB", "NOUN"], "CONJ", ["ADJ", "ADV", "NOUN"], "ADV"]`
i.e the first word is definitely a DET
the 2nd word is definitely a NOUN
the 3rd word could be a VERB or a NOUN
the 4th word is definitely a CONJ
the 5th word could be a ADJ, ADV or NOUN
the 6th word is definitely a ADV.

So INPUT = `["DET", "NOUN", ["VERB", "NOUN"], "CONJ", ["ADJ", "ADV", "NOUN"], "ADV"]`

I need the function to return each possible combination as a list of lists. So the return value for the above should be:

```
[["DET", "NOUN", "NOUN", "CONJ", "NOUN", "ADV"],
 ["DET", "NOUN", "NOUN", "CONJ", "ADV", "ADV"],
 ["DET", "NOUN", "NOUN", "CONJ", "ADJ", "ADV"],
 ["DET", "NOUN", "VERB", "CONJ", "NOUN", "ADV"],
 ["DET", "NOUN", "VERB", "CONJ", "ADV", "ADV"],
 ["DET", "NOUN", "VERB", "CONJ", "ADJ", "ADV"]]
```

The sentences could be from one to n words long. Each word might come back with from one to n parts of speech.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and the associated recipes.  It looks like you want to consider the Cartesian product of all possible POS assignments.  This can be easily done, although it's more convenient to have all elements of INPUT be lists, even if they're only lists of one.  Anyway:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> INPUT = ["DET", "NOUN", ["VERB", "NOUN"], "CONJ", ["ADJ", "ADV", "NOUN"], "ADV"]
>>> 
>>> I = [[kind] if type(kind) != list else kind for kind in INPUT]
>>> I
[['DET'], ['NOUN'], ['VERB', 'NOUN'], ['CONJ'], ['ADJ', 'ADV', 'NOUN'], ['ADV']]
```

so these are the possibilities we want to choose from.  This is what `itertools.product` is for:

```
>>> possible_assignments = list(itertools.product(*I))
>>> possible_assignments
[('DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'CONJ', 'ADJ', 'ADV'), ('DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'CONJ', 'ADV', 'ADV'), ('DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'CONJ', 'NOUN', 'ADV'), ('DET', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'CONJ', 'ADJ', 'ADV'), ('DET', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'CONJ', 'ADV', 'ADV'), ('DET', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'CONJ', 'NOUN', 'ADV')]
```

which if I understand you is what you want.  Well, they're tuples, not lists, but that shouldn't matter.

---